# Rails: Paperclip gem / where-clause inside image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling with adding a .where-clause to an image_tag. The goal is to show the Brand image from the table Brand when the `current_user.brand`is equal to an existing Brand.

Here is the code in my views:

`<%= image_tag ((Brand.where(company: current_user.brand)).logo.url(:thumb)) %>`

But this does not work. I'm getting this error:

> undefined method `logo' for Brand::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffd06dc2458

On the Brand index page itself I can show the logo with this:

```
<% @brands.each do |brand| %>
  <%= image_tag brand.logo.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```

The DB-scheme for the Brand table:

```
t.string   "logo_file_name"
t.string   "logo_content_type"
t.integer  "logo_file_size"
t.datetime "logo_updated_at"
```

Do you have any ideas how to achieve that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined method `logo' for
>   Brand::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffd06dc2458

You are calling `logo` on an ***AR relation***, not on a ***single record***, so is the error.

Instead you can just define an instance variable like below

```
@user_brands = Brand.where(company: current_user.brand)
```

and iterate through it

```
<% @user_brands.each do |brand| %>
  <%= image_tag brand.logo.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```